# USA - H1B Visa Stamping. What salary should I enter in DS 160 form if my W2 wage is more than LCA wage by $27k

Tags: usa, working-visas, h1-visa

I am filling my DS 160 form to schedule visa appointment in India for H1B visa stamping. My W2 wage is more than LCA wage by $27k. What salary should I enter in DS 160 form?

Answer (score 1):

When asked for what you will be, or are, being paid as employee, the salary should be the actual amount to be earned. The [Labor Certification Wage (LCA)](https://www.foreignlaborcert.doleta.gov/pdf/H1B_H1B1_E3_Round3FAQs.pdf) for the position is used by **employers** as supporting evidence for an H-1B petition.